# VB6 Open Forms from array

Tags: forms, vb6

I have a project in VB6.
I have aprox 800 forms.
Can I open/load a form from a list or array.

For example something like this.

```
Dim I As Integer
Dim Name As String
Dim Forms() As String
Name = "Form1|Form2|Form3|Form4|Form5 ...."
Forms = Split(Name, "|")
For I = 0 To UBound(Forms)
    Form(Forms(I)).Load
Next I
```

Be aware of that, there no loaded forms previously.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will accomplish what you need.

```
   Dim f As Form
   Set f = Forms.Add("Form2")
   f.Show vbModal, Me
```

In this example, a non-loaded form is dynamically added to the Forms collection and then shown to the user.

Comment: I want something like this:
`For I = 0 to Ubound(Forms)`
`Dim I As Form`
`Set I = Forms.Add(Forms(I))`
`I.Show vbModal, Me`
`Next I`
If you understend me. I want to load a form with form name from array with click on a button.

Comment: You could put the code from your comment into a button click event.  As it stands now, your code will show all 800 forms.  If this is not what you want, then simply supply the correct form name similar to my example.

Answer (score 0):

VB6 new form + 1 button

```vb6
Option Explicit
Public I As Integer

Public Sub Command1_Click()
    CreateForm
End Sub

Public Sub CreateForm()
    Dim Form As Form
    I = I + 1
    Set Form = New Form1
    Form.Caption = I
    Form.Show
End Sub
```

If you click button in first form. they will create duplicate form with caption increase every time button click.